# How to match location for extension less files in nginx?

Tags: regex, file, nginx, location, match

To match files with specific extensions we can use this :

location ~ .*.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
}

And all works as expected...

But what in case we have files without any extension, how could i match them in a 'location' block ?!

Answer (score 4):

The regex `.*.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$` matches any number of characters (`.*`) followed by another character (`.`) and zero or one occurence of the listed extensions `(...)?`. This regex should already match files without extension because of the `?`, as you can verify [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

**Update after clarification in comment**

You can use the regex `[^.]+(?!(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py))$` which means match more than one characters that must not be a period and are not followed by the listed extension.

**2nd Update**

According to the [docu of location](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location):

> there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead,
>   match the target regular expression and assign an empty block

So you want to match every file that has an extension and assign the empty block. It's similar to your original regex but without the `?` and you better escape the dot before the extension otherwise it means any character.

```
location ~ .*\..+$ {}
```

Comment: Hello, maybe i wasn't clear enough.

What i want is to match now 'only' extension less files !

Comment: What if i wanted something different... forget this example i provided you with 'extensions', i want to ignore 'any file' which have an extension, and accept only files which are extension less, how could i do it ?

Comment: You will have to use a negative lookahead to make sure there isn't an extension.

Comment: Sorry buy i got lost with the negative lookahead part :(

Comment: @MarkWurkz Updated. What do you think? Do you want that files with any extension are blocked or only with the given extensions (php, jsp...)?

Comment: Hello, what i want is this :

there are files in the directory :
/test.php
/a.php
/a.jpg
/a.bmp
/a.txt
/pid
/abcd
/test

and so on...

i want a regex rule that will match 'only' the files abcd, test or pid, the extension less ones...

Comment: @MarkWurkz Try `location ~ .*\..+$ {}`. Every file with an extension is assigned the empty block and not served.

Comment: Hello, It almost worked !!

It have just one issue, it is confusing directory, with extension less files, for example : 

http://www.myserver.com/folder/ (is served by that location filter too) but it should allow only : http://www.myserver.com/file

In the URL i guess a 'end' slash, is what makes the difference between a folder or file, not sure if it helps...

Comment: @MarkWurkz Instead of matching every character after the dot only match characters except the `/`. `location ~ .*\.[^/]+$` should be the solution :)

Comment: Now the files are not matched :(

Comment: @MarkWurkz It's jinxed :) But I have another one :): `.*/.+(\..{1,3}|/)$`

Comment: Now it didn't liked the regex nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in ".*/.+(\.." in /etc/nginx/vhosts/webus01.svr2.local:38

Comment: Hey, do you have any other idea ? :O

Comment: @MarkWurkz In the last one I forgot to escape the `/`. Try `.*\/.+(\..{1,3}|\/)$`

Comment: Same, still showing an error : nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in ".*\/.+(\.." in /etc/nginx/vhosts/webus01.svr2.local:38

Comment: :( anybody else have any other idea ?

Comment: I am really seeking for help, if anyone can help me would be of a great help !!